# Can I pip install python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

If I have an older version of python (e.g. python3.4) and pip for this version of python, can I install a newer version of python (e.g. python3.6) by pip? In other words, can I do this?

```
pip install python3.6
```

Comment: No, but you can you use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: apt install python-3.6

Comment: @AChampion After a quick glance of web page, `pyenv` seems to manage multiple versions of python already installed, but it doesn't seem to help installing another version of python. Or, does it?

Comment: BTW if you don't know, python 3.7 is out so you might want that instead of python 3.6

Comment: @Silencer Thanks, but I don't have a root privilege and am looking for a user land solution. I planed to use pip under virtualenv's virtual environment, or to use the `--user` option for `pip`. Sorry that I didn't mention this part in my question.

Comment: `pyenv install 3.6`

Comment: @AChampion I see. So, it will install python itself. Thank you very much.

Comment: related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/583

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  `pip` is for installing Python packages, not Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

One way to answer your own question is to ask `pip` your question with:

```
pip search python
```

It doesn't show up, so the answer is no.

---

The most common way to install or upgrade python is using your system package manager or download an installer from its website.

Edit. For those who think it's entirely impossible to install python via pip, I suggest you run the above command first.

Comment: @norio If you are interested there is an issue tracker [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/583).

Comment: So the answer is moderated... I'd say it does show up, but if you are curious about why it's outdated you can refer to the issue tracker I posted in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, `pip` is used for installing python packages, so you need to [install python](https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/) separately.

1) You can check your python version with:

```
> python -V
```

2) For windows, you can [download and run the installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

3) Adjust System Variables So You Can Access Both Python Versions From the Command Line.

4) Open a new command prompt (the environmental variables refresh with each new command prompt you open), and type

```
> python3 –version
```